# Java Error on epaysol

Tags: java, applet

Whenever our users try to login to https://xpress.epaysol.com/ct/?bid=116112098, and they click on the capture section, a java error comes up.  We tried in IE and Firefox.  They are using Windows 10 Professional x64 and have the latest version of java.  I also added it to the exceptions sites in Java.

### Error:

```
Applet: init() executed.
Requested Scanner type: VisionX2010
Endorsement Text: CHECK IMAGE PROCESSED
Franking requested: false
Feeder Return requested: false
Trailing Edge Endorsement: false
serverName: https://xpress.epaysol.com/ct/capture/
Applet: start() entered...
Java Plug-in 11.121.2.13 x86
Using JRE version 1.8.0_121-b13 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\USERNAMEHERE
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: Fun Fact: Java 9 is deprecating the Applet API finally!! Get that unsecure trash outta here

Comment: My question is, how do I fix it, do I need an older version of java.... Is that better for you?

Comment: 1) *"a java error comes up"* Always copy/paste error and exception output! 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: For further information on the tip of @CraigR8806: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: *"do I need an older version of java"* There ***used to*** be a way to specify an applet to be run in an older version of Java, but Oracle dropped support for it, possibly because they were sick of rolling out security bug fixes for those older versions.